How do I merge these unallocated with the C drive?
Ok I screwed up somehow when trying to resize the WinRE for that windows update KB5034441 error.
How do I merge the unallocated with the C drive?


Why bother? It’s just 0.75 GB, less than 0.5 % of total space.

a) Use a different partitioning tool (e.g. GParted from Linux) to move the WinRE partition to the right, so that the free space becomes adjacent to the C: partition, then expand C: to use it.
or b) Delete the WinRE partition (after disabling it with reagentc first!), then expand C: to full size minus ~750 MB, then create the WinRE partition again and use reagentc to re-enable it.
